# Can I replace a hardwood floor board without replacing the entire floor?

Tags: floor, hardwood

I have a piece of floor that expanded and is popping up due to some water damage (attached photo).

Is it possible to just take out the piece and trim it down to make it fit? Or would I need to replace the entire floor?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can remove and replace just one board. I think Matthew explained the procedure fairly well.  I think Matthew identified the floor as tongue and groove correctly.  (The new laminated floors "snap" together completely differently.) However, I think you have other issues too: 1) There appears to be other boards that will need attention in the near future. Look at the 7th board above in the photo...that joint seems to have a split, crack, etc. developing too, and

Comment: 2) The silver-colored areas along the joints indicates movement (vertical) between the boards. This results in making the clear-coat come loose from the wood and "bridge" across the joint between the two boards. This is caused by the tongue not fit tightly into the groove of the adjacent board. I suspect you'll have many more splits, cracks, etc. in the future. In fact, you may want to consider removing and replacing a much larger area...like about 3' x 3'. If so, it could be much easier to remove a larger area now, rather than doing one piece now and another in a few months, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not need to replace the entire floor; the board is a different question. Typically repairing a hardwood floor involves splitting and removing one board before you can remove the adjacent ones from the tongue and grooves. Later you can replace the damaged board with the same species, or a leftover piece. (Occasionally you can pilfer one from inside a closet or remodeled space.)

That looks like a floating floor though, so you *may* be able to carefully prod that piece up and out. Possibly even undercut it a bit with a really fine trim saw or oscilating tool if you can get the entire side up.

Once you do have it out replacement is fairly straightforward. Cut away the bottom side of the groove and run a thin bead of adhesive along the adjacent tongue, then slide the board into place at an angle inserting the tongue into the place then pressing the half-groove down into the glue.